# Can't set a default value to INT(11) altering table

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am trying to alter a table and set a default value for a nullable column. But i get the following error.

Here is the command:

```
ALTER TABLE `questiontboard`.`questions` 
CHANGE COLUMN `status` `status` (11) NULL DEFAULT 1 ;
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(11) NULL DEFAULT 1' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `questionboard`.`questions` 
CHANGE COLUMN `status` `status` (11) NULL DEFAULT 1

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1050: Table 'question' already exists
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the data type. Did you mean

```
ALTER TABLE `questiontboard`.`questions` 
CHANGE COLUMN `status` `status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT 1 ;
                                ^^^
```

Comment: This is embarrasing. Mysql Workbech auto generated this command on a INT(11) column. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be this:

```
ALTER TABLE `questiontboard`.`questions` 
CHANGE COLUMN `status` `status` int(11) NULL DEFAULT 1 ;
                                ^^ here add int as you want the datatype
```

You are missing datatype of field in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when altering a table.  I did the exact same thing you did (minus the code typo).

I got the error when altering a column from a SMALLINT to a varchar(n).  It gives the "1050 Table already exists..." error.  The error was confusing.  Of course the table exists, that's why I'm trying to alter it!

In the end, I found out that the problem was that my new varchar(2) was not big enough to hold all the original smallint data.  I had one row that had a 4 digit number, so varchar(2) wouldn't work.  I changed it to use varchar(4), and it worked.

ALTER TABLE `omiccom_wp`.`myTable` 
CHANGE COLUMN `myColumn` `myColumn` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ;